# application doesn't debug on iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, ipod

When I run my application on iphone then I can't debug it, on simulator I can. It doesn't give any error or any message, xcode keep saying that my app is running but my app gets stuck while showing splash screen.

To run application, I need to stop debugger in xcode then restart my application on iphone. I am using xcode v3.2.5.

I reinstalled my xcode but nothing happened.

My console output is

unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/GameKitServices
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes

Comment: What is the output of the console? When you build on the phone?

Comment: I attached it with my post now

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1
2. Restart XCode
3. Go to organizer and agree to let it download what it wants

works perfectly fine for me :)